# How .Net 2.0 supports LINQ in VS2010 

Tags: c#, linq, .net-2.0

We have been working on a .NET 2.0 solution loaded in VS 2010. **Our IDE allows us to write Lambda Expression, LINQ queries, etc., eventhough our project framework is set to 2.0 (I could see the .NET Framework version in the project properties).**

We are able to implement Predicate against our List. I wonder how it is possible when our project framework is 2.0 which is loaded in Visual Studio 2010.

Please advise.

Answer (score 3):

Lambda expressions and even query expressions are *C#* features, not framework features. When expression trees aren't available, you can still write lambda expressions which convert to delegate types. `List<T>` and `Predicate` existed in .NET 2.0, so it's fine. If you use something like [LINQBridge](http://code.google.com/p/linqbridge/downloads/list) you can even use LINQ to Objects in .NET 2.0, and I believe there *are* ways of even using Mono's implementation of expression trees against .NET 2.0.

I have a [short page](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Versions.aspx) listing which C# 3 features are available when targeting .NET 2.0. At some point I should update it with a similar analysis for C# 4 features against earlier versions.

Comment: However, the `Enumerable` class (containing `Select`, `Where` etc extension methods) is part of System.Core, which is not available for .NET 2.0 (you need 3.5 for that).

Comment: @Steven: The use of `Enumerable` isn't baked into the C# compiler - you just need *an* implementation of LINQ to Objects, which may or may not be in `System.Linq.Enumerable`. Getting the compiler to recognize extension methods is the slightly trickier bit.

Comment: True, but it is something you need to be aware of. But agreed, you just need .NET 2.0 and C# 3.0 to do LINQ.

Comment: Thanks for the update.

I have foreach() with in a foreach(), which takes lot of time to process a complex calculation. Is there a better way to improve this by avoiding foreach() in 2.0 framework.

Please suggest.

Comment: @Sriram: We can't possibly say without knowing what your code is meant to be doing. Maybe there's a way to speed it up - maybe there isn't. Please post code and purpose.